# Least value of $C$ for which $CT_n+1$ is always a triangular number.

Tags: combinatorics

> For $n \geq 1$, the $n$th triangular number is defined as $T_n = 1+2+\cdots+n$. Let $C$ be the least positive integer such that $CT_n + 1$ is a triangular number for all positive integers $n$. How many factors does $C$ have?

**Attempt**

We have that $T_n = \dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $CT_n+1 = \dfrac{Cn(n+1)}{2}+1 = \dfrac{Cn(n+1)+2}{2} = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{2} \implies Cn(n+1)+2 = k(k+1)$. We must find a $C$ such that for every $n$ there exists an integer $k$ that satisfies the relation. How do I proceed?

Comment: Hint: an integer $m$ is triangular if and only if $8m+1$ is square.

Comment: @MichaelLugo Is there a more elementary approach to this question without using that fact? Or is it hard to prove that fact?

Comment: Easy - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$m = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$,
$2m = n(n+1)
=n^2+n
$
so
$8m = 4n^2+4n
$
or
$8m+1 = 4n^2+4n+1
=(2n+1)^2
$.

For the reverse way,
if $8m+1$
is a square,
it must be the square
of an odd number,
so
$8m+1 = (2n+1)^2$,
and just do the above in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing your attempt: If $Cn(n+1)+2 = k(k+1) = (k+\frac12)^2 - \frac14$, then $Cn^2+Cn+2+\frac14 = (k+\frac12)^2$ is a square. This implies that the quadratic equation (in $n$)
$$Cn^2 + Cn + \frac94 = 0\tag1$$
has two identical roots, so the discriminant of (1) is zero:
$$
C^2 - 9C = 0\tag2
$$
The only positive solution to (2) is $C=9$.

As a check, with $C=9$ we have  $Cn(n+1)+2=(3n+1)(3n+2)$.

Comment: How did you get $Cn^2+Cn+\dfrac{9}{4} = 0$ and that it has two identical roots?

Comment: Suppose a quadratic expression equals a square. Then the quadratic expression factors into two identical terms, which means the equation 'quadratic expression = 0' must have two identical roots. I'm not implying that $n$ has to satisfy the equation $Cn^2+Cn+\frac94 = 0$, only that the discriminant of that equation has to be zero.

Comment: So what you are saying is that for any $n$ there exists exactly one $k$? That makes sense since for any number that is a triangular number there is exactly one triangular number that is that.

Comment: Yes, the argument shows that there is only one positive $C$ that meets the requirement, and it happens to be the same $C$ for every $n$.

Comment: ... and having found that unique value for $C$, there's only one positive $k$ that satisfies the equation $Cn(n+1)+2=(k+\frac12)^2 -\frac14$ (the other value for $k$ is negative.)

Comment: I'm not sure. Take the simple equation $x^2 = 4$. This factors into $(x-2)(x+2) = 0$ which does not have two identical roots.